# Two graphs, two axis, one figure....stumped.

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot 2 separate graphs from a dataset which have different x and y ranges.   I am confused about the interaction between plt.figure, plt.subplot and plt.axes.

Assume I am attempting to plot lines which represent an value ("ROI") for different characteristics (loans characterized by letters A - G) for different terms of loans('term').  The range of 'issue date' is different for each loan term (e.g., for term = 36, loans have been originated since 2007, for term = 60, loans have been only originated since 2011).

Here's some pseudo-code for what I have.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

alpha_grades = ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G')

color_scheme = {'A':'b','B':'g','C':'r','D':'c','E':'m','F':'y','G':'k'}

for term in [36,60]:
    for grade in alpha_grades:
        if ( term == 36 ):
            plt.figure(1,figsize=(12,9))
        else:
            plt.figure(2,figsize=(12,9))

    df[(df['grade'] == grade) & (df['term']==term)].groupby(
        'issue_date')['ROI'].mean().plot(color=color_scheme[grade],label = ("Grade: %s" % grade))
    plt.legend(loc=2)
    title = ("%i Mo Lending Rate by Rating" % term)
    plt.title(title)
```

The screen and file output for this current iteration sizes the first graph (term ==36)  much smaller than the second.  I thought by defining 2 separate figures with the same fig size I could get away from that?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: When you call `plt.figure` it creates a new figure. More likely, you want to call `plt.subplot`. The first call should look like `plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)` and the second `plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)` (the arguments are: nrows, ncols, plot_number).

Comment: @askewchan - thanks, I tried that earlier and had better results, but the plot used the same X axis.   Not sure how to get around that.  I found MATPLOTLIB to be very confusing.

Comment: Haha, yes, matplotlib _is_ very confusing, but it's the best we have in python (as far as I know). If you can make an example that doesn't depend on your data (you can just make it random), people can help more. Right now I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "same X axis".

Comment: @askewchan - Thanks.  By "same X Axis" I mean the plots where graphed over each other and only the bottom graph had a labeled axis, which was used to fit both series.   Its tough for me to make a random dataset, but if I told you that the x-axis is a series of dates (in form MMYYYY), and that the dates for term value = 36 is from 2007 - 2012, while the dates for term value =60 is from 2010 - 2012, would that help?  Its tough for  a newbie to quickly invent a dataset which illustrates this problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A figure is basically a window.  That window can have one or more axes, where each axes is a plot. `plt.subplot` lets you create multiple axes in a figure.  Both a figure and an axes are objects, with their own methods.  For example, `plt.plot` is just a thing wrapper around an `axes` object's `plot` method.

In your case you don't want to call any of these directory.  Instead, you should call `plt.subplots()` (note the "s" at the end).  This a convenience function that will create a figure, put one are more axes in that figure, and then return both the figure and all the axes.  You can then pass the axes to the pandas `plot` function to force it to plot on that axes.  You can also call set the `legend`, and `title` for that axes, but it is probablz easier to do that inside pandas.

So something like this should work (I simplified a few things as well):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

alpha_grades = ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G')

color_scheme = {'A':'b','B':'g','C':'r','D':'c','E':'m','F':'y','G':'k'}

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9)) # same as plt.subplots(1, 1)
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9))

for term, ax in zip([36,60], [ax1, ax2]):
    ax.hold(True)
    for grade, color in color_scheme.items():
        df2 = df[(df['grade'] == grade) & (df['term']==term)]
        df3 = groupby('issue_date')['ROI'].mean()
        df3.plot(ax=ax, color=color, 
                 label=("Grade: %s" % grade))
    ax.hold(False)
    ax.legend(loc=2)
    ax.set_title("%i Mo Lending Rate by Rating" % term)

fig1.show()
fig2.show()
```

Note that, rather than using `plt`, you are interacting with the figure and axes directly.

If you want to put both plots in a single figure, say one on the left and one on the right, you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

alpha_grades = ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G')

color_scheme = {'A':'b','B':'g','C':'r','D':'c','E':'m','F':'y','G':'k'}

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12*2,9))  # creates two axes

for term, ax in zip([36,60], axs):
    ax.hold(True)
    for grade, color in color_scheme.items():
        df2 = df[(df['grade'] == grade) & (df['term']==term)]
        df3 = groupby('issue_date')['ROI'].mean()
        df3.plot(ax=ax, color=color, 
                 label=("Grade: %s" % grade))
    ax.hold(False)
    ax.legend(loc=2)
    ax.set_title("%i Mo Lending Rate by Rating" % term)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the code didn't work.   I now see one blank graph (with axis but no plot) and the second graph with two plots overlaid.  Also I note that the ax.title method threw out an error.  Lastly, I got the warning:  "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py:387: UserWarning: matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure
  "matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, "

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you coded this with two different dfs (df2, df3)?   I'm certain you are also missing a reference to df2 in the groupby command.  I used my original line, it should be the same, n'est ce que pas?

Comment: I think I figured (part of it) out:  I missed the 'ax=ax' assignment in your df3.plot call.    Still getting error on the ax.title line - message is: "'Text' object is not callable."

Comment: Sorry, it should be `set_title`.  Fixed.

Comment: Yes.  Works.    Thank you.  Any stylistic suggestions for dealing with a larger number of graphs?  Eg, say I wanted to graph each 'grade' separately?   e.g., I'd place small graphs in a display (say 9x9) and save larger graphs to a file. Still not 100% confident on how to a) use axes, and b) how I can create loop and define/call different axes...

Comment: If this is what you were looking for, please mark the answer as correct.  Stylistically, I would not have more than a 3x3 grid of axes on a single figure, I would plot to individual files.  As for axes in a loop, look at the `subplots` documentation.  It creates a `(n, m)` numpy array of `Axes` objects, matching the shape of the axes in the figure.  You can loop over that as you would loop over any other numpy array, and either pass an individual `Axes` object to pandas, or plot using it directly, such as with `ax.plot(x, y)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'll try that.   Marked answer as correct.